# String join element's order

Tags: c#, string

I was doing some debugging, and I found weird thing. Why

```
string.Join("3", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

returns

```
2019312330
```

instead

```
3201912330
```

Comment: `string.Concat("3", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);`

Comment: The first argument in the `String.Join` method is the separator. So you get a 3 between each other argument/each value in an array you pass in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want `Concat`, not `Join`:

```
string result = string.Concat("3", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

Please, note, that in case of `Join` `"3"` (first argument) is a *delimiter*:

```
string.Join("3", "A", "B", "C");
```

returns `"A3B3C"`

Answer (score 2):

The first argument is used in between the other arguments.

For the expected result use

```
string.Join("", "3", DateTime.Now.Year, ...
```

Or use

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("3yyyyMd")
```

Comment: `ToString("3yyyyMd")` is really nice idea

Comment: Yes, I don't like the multiple calls to DateTime.Now.

Answer (score 0):

`string.Join()` is just to concatenate elements with separator which you specify in first parameter i.e delimitor,

```
string.Join("3", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
```

This line will return string like : `DateTime.Now.Year+"3"+ DateTime.Now.Month +"3"+ DateTime.Now.Day`

but you want to concatenate 3 with DateTime in `"yyyyMd"` format, so you can try

```
string result = $"3{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMd")}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using **string.Join(string separator, params obj[] array)** method, which Concatenates the elements of an object array, using the specified separator between each element.

That's why after each array element i.e.Year,Month and Day you are getting "3".

Use **string.Concat(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)** .